# How to use column names as x values to plot time-series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-visualization

How to plot a pandas dataframe where columns are the values at each timestep and each row corresponds to a different timeseries?

For example, I want to plot data frame below, where the x axis is the column values (1,2,3), the y-axis is the value at each row, and each row is the hue of plot (colored by product). All lineplots would be on the same figure

For timeseries 1, it should plot (1,2), (2,2), (3,0) and lineplot should be labeled with timeseries 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['timeseries1', 'timeseries2', 'timeseries3', 'timeseries4', 'timeseries5'], 
          1: [2,21,2,14,15], 
          2:  [2,3,9,22,44], 
          3: [0, 32, 0, 11,2]})
```

It is possible to do it using a loop, but is there a way to do it directly using pandas plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easier through the transpose of the data:

```py
ax = df.T.iloc[1:].plot()
_, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend([f"timeseries{int(j)+1}" for j in labels])
```

`iloc[1:]` is to avoid `product` column and last two lines revise the label names